# Trying to find data pairs anywhere in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I have an excel sheet where I want to loop through `Sheet1` and find data pairs similar to `Sheet2`. So, I have for example `A1:B1` and I need to find a row on `Sheet2` that has exactly the same values next to each other (but it could be `A33:B33` or anywhere) and copy the row over to `Sheet1` (in column C or anything)

I am also trying to make it a dynamic loop so it checks for `A1:B1` pair against `Sheet2` then `A2:B2` and so on until the last row.

Now the code I have only checks if `A1:B1` on `Sheet1` matches `A1:B1` on `Sheet2` (but not anywhere on the sheet). Also, I cannot make it so that it dynamically checks against every row on `Sheet1` (I tried to make it with the `x = x + 1` but it doesn't work)

Here is my code:

```
Sub matchme()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    r = lastrow = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    

    For x = 1 To r    
        If sh1.Range("A" & x) = sh2.Range("A" & x) And sh1.Range("B" & x) = sh1.Range("A" & x) & sh2.Range("B" & x) Then 
            sh1.Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("C" & x)    
        x = x + 1    
    Next x


End Sub
```

Please help, I have been struggling with this for days now and I need to hand in a report by the end of today, and I just cannot find anything helpful on the internet. I really appreciate any advice

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to resolve this with a script?

Comment: You could use the `Find` method and then you wouldn't have to loop through every cell.

Comment: Sorry, didn't fully get the question at first read, didn't read the looping from row to row part properly.  I've removed the comment :o)  @SJR is right, code using excels functions like `.find` and `.match` for example

Comment: @SJR but if were to use Find then I wouldn't be able to dynamically change data-pairs to check for without a loop right? Could you please illustrate your method with a code, I am not too familiar with Find and Match to be honest :o/

Comment: Not sure what you mean - I've posted some code below so let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use loops, try that:

```
Sub matchme()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastRow2 As Long
    Dim lastCol2 As Long

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastrow = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With sh2
        lastRow2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol2 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
    End With

    For x = 1 To lastrow

        For i = 1 To lastRow2

            For j = 1 To lastCol2

                If sh1.Cells(x, 1) = sh2.Cells(i, j) Then

                    If sh1.Cells(x, 2) = sh2.Cells(i, j + 1) Then

                        MsgBox "Found match!"

                    End If

                End If

            Next j

        Next i

    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this.

I've assumed you are searching for sheet1 A values in sheet2 column A only.

When a match is found, the column C value on sheet2 is copied to column C on sheet1.

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range, s As String, r As Range

With Sheet1
    For Each r In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rFind = Sheet2.Columns(1).Find(What:=r.Value, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            s = rFind.Address
            Do
                If rFind.Offset(, 1).Value = r.Offset(, 1).Value Then
                    r.Offset(, 2).Value = rFind.Offset(, 2).Value
                End If
                Set rFind = Sheet2.Columns(1).FindNext(rFind)
            Loop While rFind.Address <> s
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the pairs of Sheet1 and look for them in Sheet2:

[image]

I've used this code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim rng As Range

Dim wk1 As Worksheet
Dim wk2 As Worksheet

Dim SearchThis As String

Set wk1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wk2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = wk1.Range("A" & wk1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'<--------------------------------->
'For more type of SPECIAL CELLS, and choose exactly the type you need
'please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells

For i = 1 To LastRow Step 1
    SearchThis = UCase(wk1.Range("A" & i).Value & wk1.Range("B" & i).Value)

    For Each rng In wk2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
        If UCase(rng.Value & rng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = SearchThis Then
            'code to copy where you want
            Debug.Print rng.Row
        End If
    Next rng

Next i

Set wk1 = Nothing
Set wk2 = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The output of this code is:
[image]

Those are the row numbers where the pairs are. You just need to add a code to copy the entire row.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try below code (comments in code):

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
lastRow = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
iLastRow = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 To lastRow
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        If sh1.Cells(j, 1) = sh2.Cells(i, 1) And sh1.Cells(j, 2) = sh2.Cells(i, 2) Then
            sh1.Cells(i, 3) = "Write some information"
        End If

        'you don't need to increment loop variable "Next" does it for you
        'also i is better suited for iterator name :)
    Next
Next
```